# Calling PDF after publishing

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I have a mypdf.pdf file that I added to the Resource folder of my project. Then I set the "Build Action to Content" and the "Copy to Output Directory" to Copy if newer. Now I have this button that calls the PDF when clicked:

```
Private Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnReport.Click
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mypdf.pdf")
End Sub
```

Then I build my project using the `Build>Publish Test`. Then I installed the program to my PC and run the program. But when I clicked the button, I'm getting an error and it doesn't load the PDF.

Comment: What error? What app is generating the error? Acrobat? Visual Studio? Your app?  FWIW, Acrobat really wants exclusive locking of PDF files and doesn't play well with other apps accessing a file it has a lock on.

Comment: I already got it. I changed my code to this 
`Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\mypdf.pdf")`